# Selecting text in a div programmatically using position values belong to that text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div and there is a text in it.I want a part of that text to be selected programmatically according position value of characters.

```
<div id="textdiv">
Hello world. I am a friend.
</div>
```

I want "llo world" part to be selected(*I mean highlighted/selected like making selection of content in an input/textarea* ). In that case position values are first (3) and last (10).

How can i do that programmatically using position values?

Comment: You could have a real text-cursor-selection or a text-background, what do you want?

Comment: text-cursor-selection

Comment: Why don't you use input/textarea? Or let me rephrase: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to select a text in textarea and then show selected text in a div

Comment: but i couldnt manage this part that i asked.

Comment: Dude, this is a wholly different question now. Please edit or better ask a NEW question about "how to retrieve cursor selected text from a textarea and show it in a div".

Comment: well everybody missed that part -> "I mean highlighted/selected like making selection of content in an input/textarea".

Comment: We didn't miss it. We just understood it in another way than you were trying to say it. Highlighting and selecting are also two different things. And you said you wanted to select text in a div, not in a textarea.

Comment: i know how to get cursor position, what i dont know is to show it selected in another div.

Comment: i want part of text in a div selected (selected as in textarea/input)!

Comment: please try to select a text in input/textarea and see the difference between it and highlighting only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple way to to this:

```js
function selectTextRange(obj, start, stop) {
  var endNode, startNode = endNode = obj.firstChild

  startNode.nodeValue = startNode.nodeValue.trim();
  
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(startNode, start);
  range.setEnd(endNode, stop + 1);
  
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

selectTextRange(document.getElementById('textdiv'), 3, 10);
```

```html
<div id="textdiv">
  Hello world. I am a friend.
</div>
```

---

Text highlight:

```js
function highlightRange(el, start, end) {
  var text = el.textContent.trim()
  el.innerHTML = text.substring(0, start) + 
    '<span style="background:yellow">' +
    text.substring(start, end) + 
    "</span>" + text.substring(end);
}

highlightRange(document.getElementById("textdiv"), 3, 10)
```

```html
<div id="textdiv">
  Hello world. I am a friend.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! but this is not what i want. I want highlighting as in textarea or input.

Comment: i got error in addrange(range)  method and it says: The given range and the current selection belong to two different document fragments.

Comment: i have no idea what it is :(

Comment: @cinfis in this example?

Comment: yes...actually i think your code works great. But when i try it in my code i got error for some reason.

Comment: @cinfis and how should I guess where the error is when I don't have your code?

Answer (score 1):

Code without any error checking ahead. Use at your own risk!

```js
function highlight(pattern) {
  
  var text = $("#textdiv").text();
  var around = text.split(pattern);
  $("#textdiv").html(around[0] + "<span class='highlight'>" + pattern + "</span>" + around[1]);
  
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  highlight("world");
  
  
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="textdiv">
  Hello world. I'm Hugo!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.html()` , `String.prototype.slice()`. To select "llo world" call `.slice()` with parameters `3, 12`

```js
$("#textdiv").html(function(i, html) {
  var selected = html.slice(3, 12);
  return html.replace(new RegExp("("+selected+")"), "<mark>$1</mark>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="textdiv">
Hello world. I am a friend.
</div>
```

Comment: i want selection as in textarea/input text selection

Comment: @cinfis _"this is not what i want."_ , _" want selection as in textarea/input text selection"_ ? No `input` , `textarea` elements appear at Question ?